# How to use the Gaussian Elimination algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, vector, gaussian

I have the task to calculate u with the gaussian Eliminiation algorithm in:

Au = b

A is a Matrix (2-dimensional-Array) looking the following:

```
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[-25.0, 50.0, -25.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, -25.0, 50.0, -25.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0, -25.0, 50.0, -25.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

b is a Vector (Array) looking the following:

```
[0.0, 1.115696, 1.115696, 1.115696, 0.0]
```

How do i use the Gaussian Elimination algorithm on this? Is there already something that java has implemented? Or how would a code look like to calculate this? Im thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: Does your assignmnet allow you to use an existing implementation or do you need to implement gaussian elimination yourself? Have you tried to google "java gaussian elimination"? If not, that is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the open source [la4j](http://la4j.org/) library for example.
Then your code might look like

```
    ...
    double[][] numbers_for_A = {
            {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {-25.0, 50.0, -25.0, 0.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, -25.0, 50.0, -25.0, 0.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, -25.0, 50.0, -25.0},
            {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}};
    double[] numbers_for_b = {0.0, 1.115696, 1.115696, 1.115696, 0.0};

    Matrix A = Matrix.from2DArray(numbers_for_A);
    Vector b = Vector.fromArray(numbers_for_b);
    GaussianSolver gs = new GaussianSolver(A);
    Vector u = gs.solve(b);

    System.out.println(u);
```

You can import library using maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.la4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>la4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```